# Lame - How to re-encode all 320kbps mp3 to 192kbps mp3

Tags: command-line, music, mp3, lame

As per title. I have lots of MP3s in 320kbps format that I need to convert to 192kbps. Currently I'm using `lame --mp3input -b 192` which creates a file of the same name but with an extra .mp3 extension. So I end up with `foo.mp3.mp3`.

I need to be able to enter a directory, scan the sub directories for any 320kbps and convert to 192kbps and overwrite if any are found. Is Lame even the best tool for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

`lame` is perfectly suited to this task, but I'm going to use `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` for this answer, because I know them like the back of my hand and because they can be generalised to more than just MP3s. First of all:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

There is no tool that I am aware of that can read media files and then over-write the input straight away: you need to use an intermediate file. For a single file, you could do:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k temp.mp3
mv temp.mp3 file.mp3
```

You could combine these into a single line:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k temp.mp3 && mv temp.mp3 file.mp3
```

the `&&` there means that the `mv` command won't be executed unless `ffmpeg` exits with a status of 0 (which means success).

To check that what bit rate a file has, you can use `ffprobe`:

```
ffprobe -show_streams -select_streams a:0 -v quiet file.mp3 | grep -F 'bit_rate=320000'
```

`-show_streams` tells `ffprobe` to show information about individual streams; `-select_streams` tells it *which* ones to select, and `a:0` means 'the first audio stream (this is important for MP3 files in the case of cover art, which is stored as a video stream). The pipe (`|`) takes the standard output of `ffprobe` and feeds it to `grep`. `grep` will only print those lines that match a given pattern -- in this case, lines that contain the string `bit_rate=320000`. If you run this on a 320k kbps MP3, you'll get a line like this:

```
bit_rate=32000
```

If you run it on anything with a different bit rate, you won't get any output at all; grep will fail to make a match, and will exit with a status of 1. This means that you can chain that command with the ffmpeg command:

```
ffprobe -show_streams -select_streams a:0 -v quiet file.mp3 | grep -F 'bit_rate=320000' && ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k temp.mp3 && mv temp.mp3 file.mp3
```

Or, a bit more readably:

```
ffprobe -show_streams -select_streams a:0 -v quiet file.mp3 | grep -F 'bit_rate=320000' &&
ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k temp.mp3 &&
mv temp.mp3 file.mp3
```

That will only act on 320 kbps MP3s. Try it with a couple of test files.

The next step is to get this working with multiple files. There are two standard ways of doing this: a `for` loop, and the `find` command. The following will act on every MP3 in a directory:

```
for f in *.mp3; do 
ffprobe -show_streams -select_streams a:0 "$f" | grep -F 'bit_rate=320000' &&
ffmpeg -y -i "$f" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k /tmp/temp.mp3 && mv /tmp/temp.mp3 "$f"
done
```

This will not go into subdirectories; in order to do so, you have to set the `globstar` shell option:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.mp3; do
ffprobe -show_streams -select_streams a:0 "$f" | grep -F 'bit_rate=320000' &&
ffmpeg -y -i "$f" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k /tmp/temp.mp3 && mv /tmp/temp.mp3 "$f"
done
```

With `find`:

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -exec sh -c 'ffprobe -show_streams -select_streams a:0 "$0" | grep -F "bit_rate=320000" &&
ffmpeg -y -i "$0" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k /tmp/temp.mp3 && mv /tmp/temp.mp3 "$0"' '{}' \;
```

All of these will run strictly sequentially -- they'll only convert one file at a time. Your processor is almost certainly capable of more than that, though; to speed things up, you could use GNU `parallel`:

```
sudo apt-get install parallel
shopt -s globstar
parallel 'ffprobe -show_streams -select_streams a:0 {} | grep -F "bit_rate=320000" &&
ffmpeg -y -i {} -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k {.}.temp.mp3 && mv {.}.temp.mp3 {}' ::: **/*.mp3
```

Or:

```
find . -name '*.mp3' | parallel 'ffprobe -show_streams -select_streams a:0 {} | grep -F "bit_rate=320000" &&
ffmpeg -y -i {} -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k {.}.temp.mp3 && mv {.}.temp.mp3 {}'
```

Comment: Spectacular answer. I've cobbled something together using lame but I'll be giving this ago. Will report back.

Comment: I'm getting this error:

`Unrecognized option 'select_streams'
Failed to set value 'a:0' for option 'select_streams'`

Comment: with avconv, replace it to: `avconv -i {} -b:a 192k {.}.temp.mp3 && mv {.}.temp.mp3 {}`

Answer (score 3):

`Lame` is one of the best you can find to do this task

You can use the command `lame -b 192 input.mp3 output.mp3`

im not good with piping commands but you can use `exiftool` to get the bit rate of the mp3 file

```
exiftool -AudioBitrate File.mp3
```

but you still need a way to pipe the commands of finding mp3 file, checking the bitrate and converting...

Comment: edited twice, fixing the command and adding bitrate